# CPanel has two entries for site, need to use SSL one

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I have a website that is meant to be using SSL, however there are two entries in Cpanel's `httpd.conf` which seem to be causing an issue. When I visit just `www.website.com` I require it to go to `https://www.website.com`. However I have to write the `https://` directly for the site to work. The secure site also has a different IP.

I am not meant to edit the `httpd.conf` directly either and am unsure as to how to change the following directives:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/websitec/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
    ## User websitec # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup websitec websitec
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
           SuexecUserGroup websitec websitec
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
       RUidGid websitec websitec
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.com combined
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/websitec/public_html/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:443>
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    DocumentRoot /home/websitec/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User websitec # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup websitec websitec
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup websitec websitec
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid websitec websitec
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/websitec/public_html/cgi-bin/
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.website.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.website.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.website.com.cabundle
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/website.com-ssl_log combined
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    <Directory "/home/websitec/public_html/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/websitec/website.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see there is obviously the unsecure directive before the secure one. And this is probably the issue, however if I try to change the IP for the site in WHM I get an error saying that the IP (2.2.2.2) is already in use. Which it is I guess.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear in your question if you are supposed to have two different entries for your same site using different IP address. I am not aware that something like this is even possible with cPanel, let alone a standalone server (unless you are running some funky non-standard setup). To me it sounds like a bug/incorrect setup. I would recommend rebuilding the httpd.conf file.

1. Backup your httpd.conf file just incase: `cp httpd.conf httpd.conf.backup`
2. Rebuild httpd.conf file by running `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf`
3. Test to see if any errors are present in your httpd.conf file `service httpd -t` or `service httpd config-test` (depending on which version of Apache you are running).

If in fact I was correct that the two entires should not be present, then this should have fixed it. Now lets move on to installing the SSL certificate.

**Basics**

1. SSL needs a dedicated IP address. You can modify the site to have a dedicated IP address by WHM: `Main >> Account Functions >> Change Site's IP Address`
2. Generate SSL certificate for your site by WHM: `Main >> SSL/TLS >> Generate a SSL Certificate and Signing Request`

   1. Send the signing request to your SSL company
3. Install the provided SSL certificate from your SSL company via WHM: `Main >> SSL/TLS >> Install a SSL Certificate and Setup the Domain`

If all is good, your SSL certificate should be installed and both `http://www.website.com/` and `https://www.website.com/` should be working fine. If you would like to setup redirection, this can be done within cPanel for that domain.